# unzip .bin file programatically in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bin

I have a .bin which i am trying to unzip programatically. The directory is a temp directory in which the.bin file is saved.

I have tried to the following

```
change the permission of bin files by typing.
chmod -c 777 filenam.bin.
now run the bin file by typing
```

here is a ruby code which i have

```
%x(gunzip #{label_path})
```

using above gunzip gives me this error

```
unknown suffix -- ignored
```

I shows error as illegal option c.

Can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the error message and _the ruby code you tried to use to unzip that failed_.

Comment: have edit my question with ruby code

Comment: You don’t need to `chmod` at all. Just run `gunzip`.

Comment: downvoter, can you please explain why?

Comment: using gunzip gives this error unknown suffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gunzip` has an option `-S` to specify a suffix of the file to be unzipped:

```
gunzip -S .bin filenam.bin
```

The above will produce file `filenam` in the same directory.